# Parse.com - How to search/retrieve secured object for current uer

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

As per parse API documentation, "Security For Other Objects".

Create a private note that can only be accessed by the current user:

```
PFObject *privateNote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Note"];
privateNote[@"content"] = @"This note is private!";
privateNote.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[privateNote saveInBackground];
```

Link: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-acls/iOS

This note will then only be accessible to the current user, although it will be accessible to any device where that user is signed in.

**Question:** How to retrieve all my private notes ? Unable to find out in documentation.

Comment: did you provide read and write ACL to User?

Comment: [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]; means read and write both are true. Other user will never have any read or write access. Its purely limited to currentUser. In documentation it says, "note will then only be accessible to the current user". But how to retrieve all my notes ?

Comment: ya its true but when you insert a note than in that there is one column named ACL in that What value it shows.

Comment: Here is the value: {"7HsCYg9bLK":{"write":true,"read":true}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've got another simple solution:

NO need to create extra column. You can simply use this:

```
PFObject *privateNote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Note"];
privateNote[@"content"] = @"This note is private!";
privateNote.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[privateNote saveInBackground];


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Note"];
NSArray *usersNote = [query findObjects];
NSLog(@"%@",usersNote);
```

It will automatically retrieve private note.

Answer (score 3):

You have one add more column in your note class named "user" it creates user pointer in your table.

```
PFObject *privateNote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Note"];
privateNote[@"content"] = @"This note is private!";
privateNote[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
privateNote.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[privateNote saveInBackground];
```

And when you want to retrieve all notes which are related to that user then you can use following code

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Note"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
NSArray *usersNote = [query findObjects];
NSLog(@"%@",usersNote);
```

in above Array u can get records.

Hope this will help to you.

Comment: Yeah I got the issue. Actually I was applying my query in wrong way. Instead of queryWithClassName I was using PFUser query. Thank you for your help

Comment: Check my answer below. We really don't need extra column.

Comment: if you use that column with pointer than u can retrieve data easily and in future if more and more data comes then there is no problem occur.
Both are right way

Comment: There is no relation with more data. ACL is designed with such principles that it can handle n number of different users without any overhead of extra management.