# Specific User in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using a parse database to store data in my iOS application, i can not provide any code. Is there a way to have an app that uses parse to hold login information in a user class but also use that information as a sorted storing method. For example(User A can only get what User A saved). I already have a login completed i just need to finish this part.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: From which table you want to fetch record? User wise?

Comment: see this link i think you will get your answer--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841988/parse-com-how-to-search-retrieve-secured-object-for-current-uer/23842267#23842267

Answer (score 0):

You have to store what user A has saved by using

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
user[@"gender"] = @"male";
[user saveInBackground];
```

when you want to access it use this

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString*gender = [user valueForKey:@"gender"]
```

Comment: What the users would do is create a file in another class with text fields and images. The app is going to have multiple users and I would like each user to be able to save and access only their projects.

Comment: Then store all users reference in user defaults for future access.